# Can't get mysql_query to work, mysql_error displays nothing

Tags: mysqli

Recently converted from mysql to mysqli and things were working fine. Connect, select still work fine but now one query fails. Here is the basic code:
Connect to database ($con) - successful.
mysqli_query to select some data from table1 (fn1, ln1, yr1) - successful.
Table data goes to $fn, $ln, $yr after mysql_fetch_array - successful.
Use the data to form an insert:

$sql = "insert into table2 (fn2, ln2, yr2) values ('$fn', '$ln', '$yr')";
mysql-query($con, $sql) or die ("Insert failed: " . mysqli_error($con));

The query fail with the Insert failed message but no reason from mysql_error.

What have I missed?

Answer (score 0):

I've try it. It work. Insert it's ok!

```
$link = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
 $qry = "insert into reputazione (iduser,star,votante,commento)
values(10,5,\"pippo\",\"commento\")";
 mysqli_query($link, $qry);
if (mysqli_affected_rows($link) > 0) {
        echo "ok!";
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Okay, I solved the problem by coding all the mysqli commands in-line and not calling functions and passing the sql statements to them. I had functions for connecting to the DB, selecting from one table, inserting into another table and then deleting from the first table.